# Highly configurable iOS UI Colors

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, xib

I'm working in an application where I have to provide a mechanism to easily customize and configure UI colors, so the client can choose the colors in a web based interface, then export that as xml file that I'll use to generate an application respecting the client choices,
for the moment I'm using a header file where I define different colors used in the application :

```
    #define AccountDefaultColor [UIColor colorWithRed:34./255. green:155./255. blue:194./255. alpha:1.]
```

So I need your help on :

- How to automatically import configuration XML file and build the client customized application.
- How to make my code (and XIB files) easily customizable,
  Greetings

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) just posting your requirement isn't a real question.

Comment: Actually I have no idea where to start, pointing me to the correct direction will be great, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I think you can manually add the XML file.
2. Write a class to read that XML file to get the color you need to use.
3. Change all your code where you need to set color using the class in step 2.

In this way it is easy for you to build app. Just to change that XML file.